# Best way to update className based on react component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the best way to update a Classname field based on the state of a react component?

I have a variable called `inverted` in the state of my react component and want to update the classname of a number of my `divs` based on whether it is `true` or `false`.

What is the best way to go about this? Should I have a separate method to update the classnames? And if so, how do I deal with the asynchronicity of the setState method? If I should update it within the div, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: You could do: `let className = this.state.inverted ? "isTrue" : "isFalse"; <div className={className}>...</div>`

Comment: I've tried this, but, while className (the constant) changes perfectly, the actual classname of the div doesn't update. Any idea why it wouldn't change?

Comment: It should. When state changes the whole component is rerendered...

Comment: @TevonStrand-Brown See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9n8tehke/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a function might help if you need the same `className` on different methods; or if your `render` method is so big that you need to break it in small pieces. But usually you only need the `className` in the `render` method.

If you have several `divs` that need the same `className`, I recommend to just use a local variable inside the `render` method. That will keep the code simple to follow and short. Check the following code snippet for an example of that:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inverted: true
    };
    this.toggleInverted = this.toggleInverted.bind(this);
  }

  toggleInverted() {
    this.setState({inverted: !this.state.inverted});
  }

  render () {
    const classNameDivs = this.state.inverted ? 'sky-blue' : 'red';
    return(
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.inverted} onChange={this.toggleInverted} />
        <div className={classNameDivs}>&nbsp;</div>
        <div className={this.state.inverted ? 'white' : 'yellow'}>
          {this.state.inverted ? 'Argentina' : 'España'}
        </div>
        <div className={classNameDivs}>&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: #c60b1e;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: #ffc400;
}
.sky-blue {
  background-color: #74acdf;
}
.white {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"/>
```

But you usually don't need to set a `className` more than once, because usually you can handle it better via CSS. For instance, the conditional `className` can be used at the parent element of all the `divs`. The `divs` then will have a regular `className` in JS and will use the conditional parent in the CSS side. Same example as before, but defining the conditional `className` only once in JS, in the following snippet:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inverted: true
    };
    this.toggleInverted = this.toggleInverted.bind(this);
  }

  toggleInverted() {
    this.setState({inverted: !this.state.inverted});
  }

  render () {
    return(
      <div className={this.state.inverted ? 'argentina-flag' : 'espania-flag'}>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.inverted} onChange={this.toggleInverted} />
        <div className='top-bottom'>&nbsp;</div>
        <div className='middle'>{this.state.inverted ? 'Argentina' : 'España'}</div>
        <div className='top-bottom'>&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
.espania-flag .top-bottom {
  background-color: #c60b1e;
}
.espania-flag .middle {
  background-color: #ffc400;
}
.argentina-flag .top-bottom {
  background-color: #74acdf;
}
.argentina-flag .middle {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"/>
```